# MYSQL COLLATE Performance

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `users` with a column `firstname` and with collation `utf8_bin`

I want to know what happens under the hood when I execute an query like

```
SELECT * FROM `users` `a` WHERE `a`.`firstname` = 'sander' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

the column `firstname` isn't an index, what happens with the performance when the command executed?

And what if the default collation was `utf8_general_ci` and the query is executed without `COLLATE`

I want to know the impact it has on a big table (8 million+ records)

Comment: This is probably more appropriate on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, since the forced collation is defined over the same character set as the column's encoding, there won't be any performance impact.

However, if one forced a collation that is defined over a different character set, MySQL may have to transcode the column's values (which *would* have a performance impact); I think MySQL will do this automatically if the forced collation is over the Unicode character set, and any other situation will raise an "illegal mix of collations" error.

Note that the collation recorded against a column's definition is merely a hint to MySQL over which collation is preferred; it may or may not be used in a given expression, depending on the rules detailed under [Collation of Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-collation-expressions.html).

Comment: Makes sense, so if the encoding stays the same, MySQL just uses a little bit different algorithm to search/order the columns (where case-insentive comparison is slower because it isn't a binary comparison).

Comment: @VisserSander: That is correct.  Collation does not affect data storage - it is only used in performing comparisons.  Note that `utf8_bin` is *not* a binary comparison (as would be conducted if the strings were treated as binary strings with the `BINARY` keyword), but rather a codepoint comparison.  Therefore, if the same codepoint can be encoded in multiple ways (not possible in `utf8`, but is possible in `utf16` because of surrogates), different strings can result in comparative equivalence.